# SPARQL: Use DISTINCT and ORDER BY with multiple valriables

Tags: sql-order-by, sparql, distinct, dbpedia

When I use DISTINCT and ORDER BY with the following query, I get an empty result

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
  
SELECT ?s_type  ?p  ?o_type 
WHERE{
?s      ?p                       ?o.
?s      rdf:type              ?s_type.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?s rdf:type ?type1 .
      ?type1 rdfs:subClassOf ?s_type.
      FILTER NOT EXISTS {
         ?type1 owl:equivalentClass ?s_type.
      }
    }.
    FILTER EXISTS {
      ?s_type rdfs:subClassOf ?superType1 .
    }.
  FILTER strstarts(str(?s_type ), str(dbo:)).

   ?o      rdf:type              ?o_type.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?o rdf:type ?type2 .
      ?type2 rdfs:subClassOf ?o_type.
      FILTER NOT EXISTS {
         ?type2 owl:equivalentClass ?o_type.
      }
    }.
    FILTER EXISTS {
      ?o_type rdfs:subClassOf ?superType2 .
    }.
  FILTER strstarts(str(?s_type ), str(dbo:)).
}
```

The result on the DBpedia endpoint is available [here](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fs_type%20%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fo_type%20%0D%0AWHERE%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fp%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo.%0D%0A%3Fs%20%20%20%20%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs_type.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Ftype1%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ftype1%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%20%3Fs_type.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ftype1%20owl%3AequivalentClass%20%3Fs_type.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20EXISTS%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs_type%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%20%3FsuperType1%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fs_type%20%29%2C%20str%28dbo%3A%29%29.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fo%20%20%20%20%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo_type.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Ftype2%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ftype2%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%20%3Fo_type.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ftype2%20owl%3AequivalentClass%20%3Fo_type.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20EXISTS%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo_type%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%20%3FsuperType2%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fs_type%20%29%2C%20str%28dbo%3A%29%29.%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on).
I'd like to eliminate duplicates and order them by ?p. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what did you try? `SELECT DISTINCT .... { } ORDER By (str(?p))` should work but just adding DISTINCT seems to get zero results (REDUCED works) . Note the `str`. But also the query seems to be close to the possible timeouts and extra work may push it over the edge and the query is aborted by the server.

Comment: It worked but REDUCED does not guarantee to eliminate the duplicates. Anyway thanks a lot. I can remove duplicates programmatically.

Comment: But it's cheaper :-) Maybe the engine does as DISTINCT as sort-reduce which is why it times out. That engine (in the mode here at least) is not streaming results (the results have a content-length header so the engine knows the length before responding => it has the whole serialization)